# Can the .NET MethodInfo cache be cleared or disabled?

Tags: .net, caching, assemblies, types, methodinfo

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163759.aspx#S7), calling `Type.GetMethods()` stores reflected method information in a `MemberInfo` cache so the expensive operation doesn't have to be performed again.

I have an application that scans assemblies/types, looking for methods that match a given specification.  The problem is that memory consumption increases significantly (especially with large numbers of referenced assemblies) since .NET hangs onto the method metadata.

Is there any way to clear or disable this `MemberInfo` cache?

Comment: How many methods are we talking here? It would take a whole lot to cause memory pressure.

Comment: Yes, there are quite a few ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. One trick would be to do this work in an AppDomain. You could create a new AppDomain, do all of your work, report your results, then unload the AppDomain. Not a trivial task and fairly slow but it is the only way to effectively unload assemblies or reflection related caches (that I know of).

Comment: I'm getting a list of assemblies to scan by calling `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`.  How do I access the currently loaded assemblies from a different AppDomain?

Comment: Pass the result of AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(a => a.FullName) to the other AppDomain and then call Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad for each.

Comment: Worth noting that this is an old question and answer and in the new dotnet core runtime you can much more easily load assemblies in a context and unload them.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the memory consumption somewhat if you don't need to execute the methods by using [Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0et80c7k.aspx). Unloading the assemblies will still require unloading the AppDomain, however, so if your problem is a leak (your program stays open, user keeps passing you new assemblies to look at indefinitely), instead of just high memory use, this won't help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do need to execute the methods that match the signature I'm searching for.

Comment: I believe you can do a reflectiononlyload, then if it matches you can do a full load of just that one assembly.