# Clearing the runtimeTypeCache

Tags: c#, reflection

I currently have a c# application where just under half the heap memory usage is used by the RuntimeTypeCache+Runtime.

There is a certain point in the application where no reflection calls are made since all the code has been compiled by the application. After this, I clear our own internal caches.

However, the System.RuntimeTypeCache is still using a considerable amount of memory, which I would like to also clear.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: We need some context

Comment: How much memory are we talking about? is this causing an issue, or is this purely for academic purposes?

Comment: 100 megabytes, so quite a large amount! No this is currently happening in production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems this has already been known to be impossible without some hacky reflection :(

[Can the .NET MethodInfo cache be cleared or disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065386/can-the-net-methodinfo-cache-be-cleared-or-disabled)